# Trouble Adding String Length

Tags: java, string

I've been learning Java and for some reason, I'm having a brain fart on how to add two strings together. In the program, I successfully have the program state what the length of the First and Last names are independently. However I would like to have the program also state how many characters there are in the name.

I know that I need to assign the string lengths to an integer variable that can be added together, but I'm just blanking at the moment.

My source code is as follows, thank you for your help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * //Program Name: stringwk7
 * //Author's Name: MrShiftyEyes
 * //Date: 05-12-2013
 * //Description:  Prompt for a user name; print initials; 
 * //              print out the reverse name, find the length of the names
 */


/**
 *
 * @author MrShiftyEyes
 */
public class stringwk7{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create first name and last name StringBuffers
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
    StringBuffer firstName = new StringBuffer(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("What is your last name? ");
    StringBuffer lastName = new StringBuffer(input.nextLine());

    // Declare two string variables using StringBuffer variables
    String fName = new String(firstName);
    String lName = new String(lastName);

    // Display the users initials
    System.out.println("Your initials are: " + firstName.charAt(0) + " " + lastName.charAt(0));

    // Displays the user's name in reverse
    System.out.println("Your name in reverse is: " + lastName.reverse() + " " + firstName.reverse());

    // Length of name
    System.out.println("The length of my first name is " + firstName.length());
    System.out.println("The length of my last name is " + lastName.length());

    // Insert a goodbye into the firstName string and display to user
    firstName = firstName.reverse(); // Change firstName back to the initial value
    System.out.println(firstName.insert(0, "See ya later, "));       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just mean the first and last name together?

```
int fullNameLength = lastName.length() + firstName.length();
System.out.println("The length of my full name is " + fullNameLength);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Josh! I was having a total brain fart! Must have been all the leftover Thanksgiving turkey still getting worked out. I appreciate your assistance. I'm always so surprised to see how quickly people respond to questions here and how they're always willing to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
(firstName + lastName).length()
```

Comment: Note that this allocates a new string object with a backing character array, then copies the contents of both strings to the backing array, then returns the length of the new string, which then will immediately be available for garbage collection. While all that does not really matter in this context, I'd still recommend to do `firstName.length() + lastName.length()` instead.

Comment: I like to code in context. Your point is well taken if it's the bottle neck of the program, however, in this context it's pre-optimization.

Comment: That's really interesting. As I am still essentially learning the basics, I look forward to learning about how to optimize code. Thanks for your help guys!